# Singing or playing up side down

Tags: voice, instruments, performing, performance-practice

I've always wanted to know how difficult is it to sing while being up side down? Remember Peter Gabriel? In one of his concerts he stands on a magnet platform in special shoes up side down and sings. And as far as i remember the guitarst was also up side down playing. I also watched one cool video where a pianist was playing up side down (can't remember the name). How hard is it? Is it very different from normal playing and (or) singing?

Comment: Regarding the pianist.  Was the piano also upside down or was it the right way up?

Comment: @JimM Yes. But it was an electric piano.

Comment: OK. Not sure that a 'real' piano would work upside down.  I think playing a keyboard instrument upside down would present an interesting challenge since the action you need to play the notes changes.

Answer (score 5):

It really isn't a whole lot harder than playing or singing right side up. It is just stage performance. It is in the best interest of performers to interesting things. The [normal challenges](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/7633617.stm) associated with being upside down would continue to apply.

Playing and singing upside down would certainly present some challenge but that would most likely be due to the discomfort of doing something odd. All of our bodily functions like swallowing and pooping work fine upside down so singing and playing guitar upside down for a few minutes should be ok.

That being said, I just tried it and it was not that hard. If you are physically able to you can probably try it on a pull up bar or off of a piece of furniture.

Comment: +1 for swallowing and pooping up side down but I hardly think that works. How did you try it? I think it's a real challenge for any musician.

Comment: I have a waist high counter in my living room so I just hung off of  that and played a little guitar, and sung a little. I was uncomfortable. I thought keeping the guitar in place might have been hard but I play standing with no strap all the time so it really wasn't.

Comment: Note I don't mean it is trivial by any means. It isn't. But compared to all the work that professional musicians have to put in to learn their instruments and perform in the first place it just isn't that hard. I suspect that few people do it because it is a relatively complicated thing to do live with  little comparable return.